# How can we store element value in wso2 esb flow ? Is using property Mediator are we able to stores more than one value?

Tags: json, xml, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

[image]Can anyone explain to me how to store more than one JSON request element value. I have used property mediators in my workflow, But every time for different values I am using property mediators extracting element value and using it. I want to avoid this repetition of use and also which is not good practice.
Can anyone suggest to me what can I use to store and how can I achieve this?

so It will be the optimization of my workflow. I have used 3-4 property mediators in my flow which is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Property Group mediator to group the properties. Please have a look at the documentation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Property+Group+Mediator

But please note that, it does not give any actual performance improvement in runtime. But in the Integration Studio, the properties can be grouped into one, which looks cleaner and the functionality of the mediation can be understood easily.

Comment: Yes, @Arunan..Have use it and working fine. Can you guide me how can I get time Zone using property mediator XPath like (GMT + 5:30). Have this expression synapse:get-property("SYSTEM_DATE", "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z")

Comment: Have a look at the following blog https://medium.com/@naduni_pamudika/how-to-access-formatted-system-date-and-time-via-wso2-esb-95b61b6e7b8e